# Optimization for Excel

Tags: optimization, excel, vba

Here is the Situation: In my Excel sheet I had a column with entries in the form 1-name. I wanted to remove the numbers, taking into account that the number can also be double digit. This by itself was not a Problem and I got it working, just the Performance is so bad. As it is now my program needs about half a second per cell entry.

My question: How can I improve the performance?
Here is the code:

```
Sub remove_numbers()
    Dim YDim As Long
    Dim i As Integer, l As Integer
    Dim val As String
    Dim s As String
    YDim = Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 8 To YDim
        val = Cells(i, 5)
        l = Len(val)
        s = Mid(val, 2, 1)
        If s = "-" Then
            val = Right(val, l - 2)
        Else
            val = Right(val, l - 3)
        End If
        Cells(i, 5).Value = val
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using 3 different functions: Len(), Mid(), Right() you could use a [Split()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x627e5f%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) function which would have been much more efficient in this case.

Try the below code

```
Sub remove_numbers()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim i As Long
    For i = 8 To Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row
        Cells(i, 5) = Split(Cells(i, 5), "-")(1)
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: Deactivating ScreenUpdating (and maybe automatic recalculation) for the runtime of a function should do the trick. Optimizing the actual code is - in my experience - a less efficient approach. (Although nonetheless desireable...)

Comment: @AlexanderKosubek efficiency of using 3 functions to achieve something you do with one can't be comparable. `Application.Screenupdating` helps a bit but the code design is what you should pay attention to.

Comment: I don't want to advocate inefficient code, but when you're at the point where you loop over many cells just turning off `.ScreenUpdating` and `.Calculation` will usually help more than investing any amount of time in serious optimization... - That's the reason I voted your answer up and didn't post my comment as a serious answer...

Comment: Ok, understood. The OP had it in his code originally just commented out. I assumed he knows what that does but you're right I could have mentioned it too in my answer.

Comment: From my experience, best achievement with this code is replacing 6/7 lines in place of one. VBA is interpreted, so whenever you reduce a line of code you gain in interpreter overheads.

Comment: +1 Fine solution, but: wouldn't it be more efficient to calculate the `TO` factor of the `FOR` line into a variable ? (YDim in the question)

Comment: @iDevlop why would you assume it would be more efficient? it's only interpreted once? isnt it?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I didnt mention it but I also used Screenupdating=False. But for me that didnt help a lot...
For me it is somewhat strange that this one fix with split changes so much, we didn't even Change the Loop. But, it helped so I am happy, thanks.

Comment: @mehow: well, if if it's interpreted once, ok. But I have no confirmation about this, hence my comment. Do you have any reference about that ?

Answer (score 3):

My suggestion:

```
Sub remove_numbers()
    Dim i As Integer, values() As Variant
    values = Range(Cells(8, 5), Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row).Value
    For i = LBound(values) To UBound(values)
        values(i, 1) = Mid(values(i, 1), IIf(Mid(values(i, 1), 2, 1) = "-", 2, 3))
    Next
    Range(Cells(8, 5), Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row).Value = values
End Sub
```

Optimizations:

- Perform all calculations in memory and them update entire range: this is a HUGE performance gain;
- Condensed multiple commands into a single command;
- Replaced `Right(x, Len(x)-n)` with `Mid(x, n)`.

EDIT:

As suggested by @Mehow, you may also gain some performance using

```
 values(i, 1) = Split(values(i, 1), "-", 2)(1)
```

instead of `values(i, 1) = Mid(values(i, 1), IIf(Mid(values(i, 1), 2, 1) = "-", 2, 3))`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is a nice and elegent solution but from directly copying it I got some errors. But after I fixed that it worked like a charm!

Comment: Sorry. But the other answer worked immediatly and was closer to my solution.

Answer (score 1):

You should manipulate the whole range values as an array and work directly with it in memory.

Something like :

```
Dim valuesOfRangeToModify() As Variant
Set valuesOfRangeToModify = Range(Cells(8, 5), Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)).Value
For Each cell In valuesOfRangeToModify 
    cell = ... // remove numbers
Next

Range(Cells(8, 5), Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp)).Value = valuesOfRangeToModify
```

My VB is quite old so it probably has syntax errors but you get the idea.
This should give a huge boost.

For reference, here is an article full of interesting advices, see point #4 for more explanation of the solution given above :
http://www.soa.org/news-and-publications/newsletters/compact/2012/january/com-2012-iss42-roper.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Also do not operate one cell at a time. Create a range of cells and transfer them into an array for processing. In the end the array can be used to replace the cells.

To tweak the answer from @mehow

```
Sub remove_numbers()
    Dim i As Long, N as Long, r as Range
    Set r = Range("B3") ' Whatever is the first cell in the column
    N = Range(r, r.End(xlDown)).Rows.Count 'Count the rows in the column
    Set r = r.Resize(N,1) ' Expand the range with all the cells
    Dim values() as Variant
    values = r.Value  ' Collect all the values from the sheet
    For i=1 to N
        values(i,1) = Split( values(i,1), "-")(1)
    Next i
    r.Value = values   'Replace values to the sheet
End Sub
```

To make it more general you can add an argument to the procedure to pass a reference to the first cell in the column, like `Sub remove_numbers(ByRef r as Range)`. There is no need to de-activate the screen as there is only one write operation in the end and you want the screen to update after that.